# Как правильно верстать такую таблицу?

Tags: html, css

Как правильно верстаются такие таблицы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое, что приходит на ум, это сделать два блока

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-one">
  <p>lineline:</p>
  <p>linelinelinelineline:</p>
  <p>linelineline:</p>
  <p>lineline:</p>
  <p>lineline:</p>
</div>
<div class="content-two">
  <p>line</p>
  <p>line</p>
  <p>line</p>
  <p>line</p>
  <p>line</p>
</div>
```

Но мне кажется это не правильным, при том, что при уменьшении размеров, один блок может перескочить под другой. Какими подходами в таких ситуциях пользуетесь Вы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть чуть фантазию включить и получится типа таблица

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

P {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

span:first-child {
  border-right: 1px dashed #000;
  width: 50%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 900;
}

span:last-child {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<p><span>здесь что то </span><span>здесь цыфра</span></p>
<p><span>здесь что то </span><span>здесь цыфра</span></p>
<p><span>здесь что то </span><span>здесь цыфра</span></p>
```

второй пример , просто так сделал

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

P {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

span:first-child {
  width: 50%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 900;
}

span:last-child {
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  height: 100%
}

span:last-child i {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

span:last-child i:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}

i:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
}

i:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>здесь что то </span>
  <span>
<i>здесь цыфра</i>
<i>здесь тоже что то</i>
</span>
</p>

<p>
  <span>какая то канитель</span>
  <span>
  <i>тут что то</i>
  <i>и тут какая то лажа</i>
  <i>и здесь хрень</i>
</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Табличные данные стоит верстать, как ни странно, таблицами. Заголовки помечать тегом `<th>`, а ячейку с данными — `<td>`.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Weight</th>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Volume</th>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: По-моему таблицы не адаптивны и их используют только в верстке писем. Или я не прав?

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi ,есть несколько способов: 1) Уменьшение отступов, шрифта и т.д. 2) Обёртка в контейнер с `overflow-x:auto` 3)Задание `display:block` для элементов таблицы. И всё-таки таблицы надо верстать таблицами, семантика и всё такое.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi не прав. Тут уже упомянули про семантику, а устроить таблицам адаптивность это дело техники.